# How can I parse string values to a workable POSIXct format when the duration of some of the values are over 24 hours?

Tags: r, string, datetime, duration, posixct

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70978243/r-how-can-i-convert-non-intuitive-strings-that-describe-hours-minutes-and-sec) previous question I asked.

I have a data set in R that has values in hours, minutes, and seconds format. However, some values only have hours and minutes, some only have minutes and seconds, some only have minutes, and some only have seconds. It's also not formatted very favorably. When I use parse_date_time() on it, the parsing only works for values that are less than 24 hours. Sample data can be found below:

```
example <- as.data.frame(c("25h28m", "17m7s", "15m", "14s"))
```

Using parse_date_time(), I get this:

| Column Title |
| --- |
| NA |
| 00:17:07 |
| 00:15:00 |
| 00:00:14 |

But would like to get this:

| Column Title |
| --- |
| 25:28:00 |
| 00:17:07 |
| 00:15:00 |
| 00:00:14 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may do this by converting to `period` class from `lubridate` and then use `hms` from `hms`

```
library(lubridate)
hms::hms(as.period(toupper(example)))
```

-output

```
25:28:00
00:17:07
00:15:00
00:00:14
```

#### data

```
example <- c("25h28m", "17m7s", "15m", "14s")
```